# Photoshop colorpickers result is blueish

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color

I just can't find a solution to the following problem. My color picker shows all colors as bluish. The resulting color is still the right one.
Does anyone here have an idea?

Note: My picker is already searching for 1 pixel.

Kind regards

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Never mid, i found it. I changed the preferences.

[image]